# Validate form fields using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, validation

I do have a jquery code to validate my form but unfornutately it is not that accurate. I would like to validate the fields thoroughly like only to accept numbers on phone field and only a valid email address on email field.

Also I would like to show the error ( or just add a red border one field ) as soon as the user types/inputs a value without clicking submit button, so it looks like a real time checker.

Can anyone derive my script, I am really not confident about this. Also derive my php code if u think it is wrong. Would love to learn how to use session also so user can only submit once every session.

Code:

```
<head>

    <script>
      $(function () {

        $('.cbf').on('submit', function (e) {

          e.preventDefault();

          var name = $('#name').val();
          var phone = $('#phone').val();
          var email = $('#email').val();

          if ( name == "" ) {
             alert('Please provide valid name');
             $('#name').addClass('error');
          }

          else if ( phone == "" ) {
             alert('Please provide a valid phone number');
             $('#phone').addClass('error');
             $('#name').removeClass('error');
          }

          else if ( email == "" ) {
             alert('Please provide a valid email');
             $('#email').addClass('error');
             $('#phone').removeClass('error');
          }

          else {
              $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'index.php',
                data: $('.cbf').serialize(),
                data: "name="+ name +"& phone="+ phone +"& email="+ email,
                success: function () {
                  alert('We will contact you shortly! Thanks!');
                },
                complete:function(){
                        $('.cbf').each(function(){
                            this.reset();   //Here form fields will be cleared.
                        });
                   }
              });

              $('#email').removeClass('error');

          }

        });

      });
    </script>

</head>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" class="cbf">

<fieldset>

    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" placeholder="Name">
    <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" value="" placeholder="Phone">
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Email Address">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Get Call Back">

</fieldset>

</form>

    <?php

    session_start();

if ('POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {

$_SESSION['posted'] = true;

$to = "myemail@gmail.com";
$subject = "Someone wants a Call Back!";

// data the visitor provided

//$name_field = $_POST['name'];
//$phone_field = $_POST['phone'];
//$email_field = $_POST['email'];

$name_field = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$email_field = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
$phone = filter_var($_POST['phone'], FILTER_SANITIZE_INT);

  //constructing the message
  $body = " From: $name_field\n\n Phone: $phone_field\n\n E-mail: $email_field\n\n";

  // ...and away we go!
  mail($to, $subject, $body);

} else {
// handle the error somehow
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
$("#signupform").validate({
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        mobile: {
            required: true,
            number: true,
            minlength: 10,
            maxlength: 10
        }
    },
    messages: {
        email: {
            required: "Please enter a valid email address.",
            email: "Invalid Email Address."
        },
        mobile: {
            required: "Please provide a mobile number.",
            minlength: "Your mobile number must be 10 characters long.",
            maxlength: "Your mobile number must be 10 characters long.",
            number: "Please Enter number only."
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple **jQuery validation**:
The form:

```
<form id="myform">
    email<input type="text" name="field1" />
    <br/>
    password<input type="text" name="field2" />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The validation part

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
            rules: {
                field1: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                field2: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
                alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
                return false; // for demo
            }
        });

    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VuPPy/

Answer (score 0):

Its better to validate on both server side and client side. Client side validate then display the error to user. On server side, you need to validate again, just because your JS code can be changed by malicious user.

A simple example with `phone`.

```
//client side
var phone = $('#phone').val();

//validate
if(/^\d+$/.test(phone) === false){ //not number
    alert('Your phone number is not valid');
}

//on server side

$phone = $_POST['phone'];
if(is_numeric($phone)){
    insert $phone into database.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use HTML5 and new tags like : "email" and "tel" (tel is not supported for the moment) :

```
<input type="tel" name="phone" required>
```

and for email :

```
<input type="email" name="email" required>
```

Even the solution you choose, you have to do a control on the server side in Php for your case.

It's not the solution but in the futur, I think we should use these tags.

More informations : http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp